# LARAVEL - Posts sorted by - Selected value after refresh (bootstrap)

Tags: php, laravel, selected

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcu6A.png)

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldr0h.png)

The situation looks like this.
When sorting, I choose options "Like" and click submit. Everything is sorted nicely, but after refreshing the page, the value in the field is "Lastest".
Is there any possibility that the value I chose would remain until the next select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a session to keep the last selected value as the default value.
[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session) you can learn about the sessions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I did it in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
I add this to select:

```
<option href="/?sortMypost=1" value="1" {{ $option == '1'  ? "selected" : "" }} >Latest</option>
```

And this to controller:

```
$option = request()->input('sortMypost');
```

And this to the end of the controller:

```
return view('posts.mypost', compact('posts', 'option'));
```